# How do I return a set of results from a Query Window in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

For this code:

`DECLARE 
    v_APPL_ID               NUMBER(10,0) := 0;
    v_ADMIN_PHS_ORG_CODE    VARCHAR2(2 BYTE) := ' ';
    v_SERIAL_NUM            NUMBER(6,0) := 0;
    v_Proj_Appl_Rec         Proj_Appl_Rec;
    v_Proj_Appl_Tab         Proj_Appl_Tab := Proj_Appl_Tab();
    v_Proj_Appl_Cur         SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_cnt                   NUMBER := 0;
    GrantApplications_CUR   SYS_REFCURSOR;`

BEGIN
    ireport_portfolios.GetPortfolioAppsAndProjects(
        null, 190, 'DYNAMIC', null, v_Proj_Appl_Cur);

```
--dbms_output.put_line('appl_id' || chr(9) || 'ic' || chr(9) || 'serial_num');   
LOOP
  FETCH v_Proj_Appl_Cur
  INTO v_APPL_ID, v_ADMIN_PHS_ORG_CODE, v_SERIAL_NUM;
  EXIT WHEN v_Proj_Appl_Cur%NOTFOUND;
  v_Proj_Appl_Tab.extend;
  v_cnt := v_cnt + 1;
  v_Proj_Appl_Tab(v_cnt) := Proj_Appl_Rec(v_APPL_ID, v_ADMIN_PHS_ORG_CODE, v_SERIAL_NUM);
  --dbms_output.put_line( v_APPL_ID || chr(9) || v_ADMIN_PHS_ORG_CODE || chr(9) ||  v_SERIAL_NUM);
END LOOP;
CLOSE v_Proj_Appl_Cur;

     OPEN GrantApplications_CUR FOR
      WITH Appls_CTE
      AS
      (
         SELECT DISTINCT
                pa.Appl_Id
           FROM TABLE(v_proj_appl_tab) pa
      )

      SELECT ga.appl_id, council_meeting_date
      FROM Appls_CTE ac
      JOIN grant_appls ga
      ON ac.appl_id = ga.appl_id;

    RETURN   GrantApplications_CUR;
```

END;

it runs fine if I comment out the RETURN statement at the bottom.
But all I see is:
anonymous block completed.
So I added the Return statement and now I get:

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 41, column 9:
PLS-00372: In a procedure, RETURN statement cannot contain an expression
ORA-06550: line 41, column 9:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

I tried taking the CTE out and just joining to "TABLE(v_proj_appl_tab) pa".
But I get the same error.

What is the last step here to be able to see the results?
How do you return results like this from a simple query window without having to write a Package PROC?

---

I tried running this from the tip below:
DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(GrantApplications_CUR);

Now I get this error:

Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "LINK_OD_IREPORT.IREPORT_PORTFOLIOS", line 217
ORA-06512: at "LINK_OD_IREPORT.IREPORT_PORTFOLIOS", line 83
ORA-06512: at line 12
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.
Now I get this error:

Answer (score 2):

In 12c they added support for Implicit Statement Results from PL/SQL via DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT.

```
declare
  l_cursor_1 SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN l_cursor_1 FOR
    SELECT table_name
    FROM   user_tables
    WHERE  rownum < 5;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(l_cursor_1);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this going.  There is no way I guess to just return the results and watch them fill up a grid nice and pretty like in SQL Server.
You always have to loop through a cursor to display results.

So basically here I call Package Proc to populate my first cursor and populate a table TYPE based on a RECORD TYPE from the first cursor.

Now I define a second cursor, and use Common Table Expressions to join to another table into the second cursor.

Now I have to loop through the second cursor and dbms_output.put_line the results.

What I was really trying to do here was take Appls_CTE coming back from GetPortfolioApplsAndProjects and join that to another table in our db to debug some of our data.

Now I think I have it figured out where I can freely join Appls_CTE to anything and start debugging this way like looking for nulls in our data.

Here is the final version:

```
DECLARE 
v_APPL_ID               NUMBER(10,0) := 0;
v_ADMIN_PHS_ORG_CODE    VARCHAR2(2 BYTE) := ' ';
v_SERIAL_NUM            NUMBER(6,0) := 0;
v_Proj_Appl_Rec         Proj_Appl_Rec;
v_Proj_Appl_Tab         Proj_Appl_Tab := Proj_Appl_Tab();
v_Proj_Appl_Cur         SYS_REFCURSOR;
v_cnt                   NUMBER := 0;

GrantApplications_CUR   SYS_REFCURSOR;
fbp_appl_id             NUMBER(10,0);
fbp_council             VARCHAR2(6 BYTE);

BEGIN
ireport_portfolios.GetPortfolioAppsAndProjects(
    null, 190, 'DYNAMIC', null, v_Proj_Appl_Cur);

dbms_output.put_line('appl_id' || chr(9) || 'ic' || chr(9) || 'serial_num');   
LOOP
  FETCH v_Proj_Appl_Cur
  INTO v_APPL_ID, v_ADMIN_PHS_ORG_CODE, v_SERIAL_NUM;
  EXIT WHEN v_Proj_Appl_Cur%NOTFOUND;
  v_Proj_Appl_Tab.extend;
  v_cnt := v_cnt + 1;
  v_Proj_Appl_Tab(v_cnt) := Proj_Appl_Rec(v_APPL_ID, v_ADMIN_PHS_ORG_CODE, v_SERIAL_NUM);
  --dbms_output.put_line( v_APPL_ID || ' - ' || v_ADMIN_PHS_ORG_CODE || ' - ' ||  v_SERIAL_NUM);
END LOOP;
CLOSE v_Proj_Appl_Cur;

     OPEN GrantApplications_CUR FOR
      WITH Appls_CTE
      AS
      (
         SELECT DISTINCT
                pa.Appl_Id
           FROM TABLE(v_proj_appl_tab) pa
      )

      SELECT ga.appl_id,
             council_meeting_date
      FROM Appls_CTE ac
      JOIN grant_appls ga
      ON ac.appl_id = ga.appl_id;

    --RETURN   GrantApplications_CUR;
    --DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(GrantApplications_CUR);

    LOOP
        FETCH GrantApplications_CUR
        INTO fbp_appl_id, fbp_council;
        EXIT WHEN GrantApplications_CUR%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(fbp_appl_id || ' - ' || fbp_council);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE GrantApplications_CUR;
END;
```